# Question About OCaml Function Signatures in UTop

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to import the following OCaml code in to  utop:

```
let rec insert (x : 'a) (l : 'a list) : 'a list =   
    match l with 
    | [] -> [ x ] 
    | hd :: tl ->
            if x = hd then l
            else if is_sorted (x :: l) then x :: l
            else hd :: insert x tl
```

When I import it though its signature is

```
val insert : int -> int list -> int list = <fun>
```

I am confused why its signature is in terms of int rather than 'a.
Could someone explain to me why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are using Jane Street modules. They redefine polymorphic comparisons to work on int, because polymorphic comparisons have a few tricky spots that tend to trip up beginning OCaml programmers.

I have trouble navigating Jane Street documentation, but I believe there is a Polymorphic_compare module where you can find the built-in polymorphic comparison operators of OCaml.

Comment: So the is_sorted function call could be the cause of this? I looked it up and is_sorted appears to be apart of the Jane Street modules.

Comment: With Jane Street modules, `if x = hd` is going to require that `x` and `hd` be ints. `=` is normally a polymorphic comparison operator but not with Jane Street. Try typing `(=)` into the toplevel and see what it says.

Comment: utop # (=);;
- : int -> int -> bool = <fun>

Comment: So you see, the normally polymorphic `=` is redefined to act only on ints.

Comment: Interesting, thank you